# using select and option javascript/jquery getting the wrong data-value using (this).data("value")

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code that send that data value to my server

```
$("#choiceamountmonthly").change(function () {
    var monthamountblock = $(this).data("value");
    alert("maandelijks pakket gekozen");

    $.getJSON(
        "server/ajax.php",
        {request:"addMonthsToCart", MonthsToCart: monthamountblock},
        function (data) {
            switch(data.response){
                case "success":
                    alert("Met succes toegevoegd");
                    break;
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Here it gets the data-value.

```
<select id="choiceamountmonthly" data-value="1000" name="subscription_choice" title="subscription_choice">
    <option data-value="0" >-Kies het aantal maanden-</option>
    <option data-value="3">3 maanden</option>
    <option data-value="5">6 maanden</option>
    <option data-value="9">12 maanden</option>
</select>
```

In my code here it takes the `data-value` of the select so it sends 1000 to my server.  But I want to send the `data-value` of the option to my server. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also use only *value* (instead of *data-value*) for select options:

```
<select id="choiceamountmonthly" 
        data-value="1000" 
        name="subscription_choice" 
        title="subscription_choice">
  <option value="0" >-Kies het aantal maanden-</option>
  <option value="3">3 maanden</option>
  <option value="5">6 maanden</option>
  <option value="9">12 maanden</option>
</select>
```

than you can grab it like this:

```
var monthamountblock = $(this).val();
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/jtMdP3E2LJMBs6CzBzLQ?p=preview

Comment: I personally think this is the better way, unless there's a specific need to use `data-value` for some reason...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
var monthamountblock = $(this).data("value");
```

What you need is:

```
var monthamountblock = $(':selected', this).data("value");
```

This grabs the selected option's data from the select, rather than the select's data itself.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That will throw a syntax error. I think you mean `$(':selected', this)`.

Comment: Thanks, essentially I was looking for `$("#choiceamountmonthly :selected");`. I just assumed that if you use `this` it would handle `:selected` in the same way. I've updated my code to correct this :)

Comment: Still not correct. You're not putting `":selected"` in a string. Please do try to run your code in a browser before posting it.

Answer (score 0):

from what i can see, you dont need the data-value on the select.
This seems to be overriding the data-value of the options.
The select should just need the name, no value.

IE:

```
`<select id="choiceamountmonthly" name="subscription_choice" title="subscription_choice">
    <option data-value="0" >-Kies het aantal maanden-</option>
    <option data-value="3">3 maanden</option>
    <option data-value="5">6 maanden</option>
    <option data-value="9">12 maanden</option>
</select>
`
```

Comment: I have tried that but then it does not send any value to the server.

Comment: ah i missed the bit in the jquery, as obisidian pointed out, you need the select the `':selected'` value

ie. `(this,':selected').data("value");`